# Text recognition from images using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am having issues with text recognition from images using pytesseract. im try screenshot in game and get info from it. with photo 1 sometime it work, sometime i just get 275 instead of 11275. with photo 2, i cannt get anything
This my code:

```
for count_check_hp in range(0,3):
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580, 554, 640, 577))
    screenshot_cv = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    preprocessed_image = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    screenshot.close()
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_image, lang='eng')
    QtTest.QTest.qWait(300)
    if len(extracted_text) > 0:
        break
try:
    value_hp = extracted_text.replace("\n", "")
    number_hp = re.findall(r'\d+', value_hp)
    number = int(''.join(number_hp))
    if len(number) > 0:
        return number
    else:
    return 99999
except Exception as error_get_hp:
    print(f'check hp error: {error_get_hp}')
    return 99999
```

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mguR.png),   [Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcIOY.png)

Comment: Can you please respond to our answers?

Answer (score 2):

I've done a project called "Image to text" using pytesseract and hope it will help you.
I think it is better to share my github repository rather than put much code here.

> https://github.com/topmsdreamer/image-to-text-converter

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKNfH.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhTq9.png)

Comment: its difficult to understand how your code reacts as it says pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical solution that is going to work with all images.
We may find a solution that works with the two sample images from your post, and hope it's going to work in most of your cases.

---

There is a certain font size that increase the chances of the succesull OCR.
Resizing the input image by a factor of x3 seems to improve the results:

```
preprocessed_image = cv2.resize(preprocessed_image, (preprocessed_image.shape[1]*3, preprocessed_image.shape[0]*3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

---

Adding `--psm 6` argument may improve the results.

> 6    Assume a single uniform block of text.

---

Adding `_char_whitelist` (limit to numbers and ',') may improve the results.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'  # May be required when using Windows

preprocessed_image = cv2.imread('photo1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale.

# Resize the image by a factor of x3 in each axis
preprocessed_image = cv2.resize(preprocessed_image, (preprocessed_image.shape[1]*3, preprocessed_image.shape[0]*3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_image, config="-c tessedit"
                     "_char_whitelist=0123456789.,"
                     " --psm 6")

print(extracted_text)  # 11,275

extracted_text_as_number = extracted_text.replace(',', '')  # Remove the comma
print(extracted_text_as_number)  # 11275



# Second image
################################################################################
preprocessed_image = cv2.imread('photo2.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale.

# Resize the image by a factor of x3 in each axis
preprocessed_image = cv2.resize(preprocessed_image, (preprocessed_image.shape[1]*3, preprocessed_image.shape[0]*3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_image, config="-c tessedit"
                     "_char_whitelist=0123456789.,"
                     " --psm 6")

print(extracted_text)  # 0
################################################################################
```